# How can I have a repeating sequence of background colors for my grid layout?

Tags: css, sass

I have a grid layout using Bootstrap and I would like to have the background colors of each grid item one of four colors. For example, let's say I have 4 colors: red, blue, yellow and green. I would like the background color of the first grid item to be red, then blue, then green, yellow, red, blue, green etc etc. Can I achieve this with CSS/SASS?

```
<div class="blog-wrapper">
  <h1 class="blog-title">Soapbox Blog</h1>



  <div class="container blog-list-container">
    <div class="row">
    {% for post in site.posts %}
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-4 mt-4">
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">
        <div class="post-thumbnail h-100"
              style="background-image: url('{{site.baseurl}}/assets/images/{{ post.image }}');">
          <!-- Content -->
          <div class="text-white text-start d-flex align-items-center rgba-black-strong p-5">
            <div>
              <h5>{{ post.format | capitalize  }}</h5>
              <h3 class="card-title pt-2"><strong>{{ post.title }}</strong></h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat fus minus error nisi architecto nulla ipsum dignissimos. amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat fus minus error nisi architecto nulla ipsum dignissimos.Odit sed qui, dolorum!.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>  <!-- end of col -->
    {% endfor %}
  </div> <!-- end of row -->
</div> <!-- end of container -->
</div> <!-- end of wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) CSS selector:

```css
.container :nth-child(1n) {background-color: red;}
.container :nth-child(2n) {background-color: green;}
.container :nth-child(3n) {background-color: blue;}
.container :nth-child(4n) {background-color: yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the HTML that I have. I think because there are many child elements of the element I would like the style on. I've added my HTML to the question

Comment: Sorry. I readed "Grid layout" and understood an actual CSS grid layout (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). BTW, I would rather advise you to move to CSS Grid which is well supported nowadays and avoid as much as possible bootstrap bullshit that only make things harder than they actually are nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-of-type for this:

you can add as much elements as you want.

```css
.container div:nth-of-type(4n + 1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(4n + 2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(4n + 3) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(4n + 4) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the HTML that I have. I think because there are many child elements of the element I would like the style on. I've added my HTML to the question

Comment: You need to edit the code so it works for you just add a class to your row items and replace div with that class